# Alternatives to GitLens VSCode extensions

Tags: git

GitLens VSCode extensions charges 60$, which is too much for me! What I need most is the Commit Graph feature in GitLens, which can let me see a file's git history. Even Sourcetree can not do that easily because it can only check the files in a specific commit. I can't just choose a file to see its git history.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to see the Commit Graph you can use something like the [GitGraph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) extension. You also have this [Git File History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pomber.git-file-history) extension to navigate a given file history.

Comment: You could improve your answer by giving them a bit more of a review.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Git Blame](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solomonkinard.git-blame)? It's fast, packed with features, and has inline blame.

[image: Git Blame]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).